# Suppose $f : [0, 1] \to (0, 1)$ is a bijection. Using $f$, construct a bijection from $[−1, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f : [0, 1] \to (0, 1)$ is a bijection. Using $f$, construct a bijection from $[−1, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't know how to approach this question. I know there are similar questions, but none of those considered a case when a bijection is from a closed interval to $\mathbb{R}$. Please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know any bijections $[-1,1] \to [0,1]$ and $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Is there a bijection from a closed interval onto an open one?

Comment: @Piquito - not a continuous one

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs: I understand now. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple task I'll leave to you to find a bijection $g: [-1,1]\to[0,1]$.

Now if we find a bijection $h: (0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$, then the map $h \circ f\circ g$ is what you are looking for.

For $h$, you should think about, for example, the tangens, which is a bijective map $\tan: (-\pi/2,\pi/2) \to \mathbb{R}$. By shifting and rescaling it in the right way, you will get the correct $h$.

Comment: There are also nice rational functions that send $(0,1)$ to the whole line. For example, $(2x-1)/(x(1-x))$ seems like it should work.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you all so much!